# Ruby/Passenger stops working after update to OpenSSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ruby, openssl

Someone has run a `yum update` on the CentOS box (`Linux 2.6.28.1-xxxx-std-ipv4-32 #2 SMP Fri Jan 30 09:55:02 UTC 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`) that runs a Ruby on Rails app ([Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/)) served with Passenger (`Phusion Passenger version 3.0.7`). As a result the RoR app stopped working and [this is what happens now](http://redmine.appleseedhq.net/).

My uderstanding is that the `yum update` command updated the OpenSSL library, which is now at version `OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008`. I suppose this version is no longer compatible with the version of Ruby installed on the machine (`ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25) [i386-linux]`). Indeed, if I do `require 'openssl'` inside `irb`, I get the following:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'openssl'
TypeError: Cipher is not a class
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/openssl/cipher.rb:22
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/openssl.rb:20:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/openssl.rb:20
        from (irb):1:in `require'
        from (irb):1
```

which is the same error as printed when accessing the application via HTTP.

I suspect that downgrading the OpenSSL version now is a risky business, since the `yum update` command probably updated other packages (e.g. mod_ssl) that now rely on the new OpenSSL library.

I decided instead to check whether Ruby 1.8.7 would work better with the new OpenSSL version. I downloaded it, built it and `make install`'ed it such that the Ruby binary resides in `/usr/local/bin/` alongside the system's Ruby (1.8.5) which is in `/usr/bin/` as usual. Doing a `require 'openssl'` in irb shows that it indeed works.

Now, my question is as follow: should I remove my own built version of Ruby and rather update the system's Ruby to 1.8.7? Or should I *somehow* instruct Passenger to use the ruby binary that I built myself (the one in `/usr/local/bin/`)?

Thanks for your help.

Cheers,
Franz

Answer (score 0):

The second way is safer than the first. You can do it with [rvm](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/):

```
rvm use 1.8.7
gem install passenger --pre
```

or [PassengerRuby](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby) directive:

```
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

About the first way, try to create symlink first:

```
mv /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby185.bak
ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: So, I went the second way. Alongside my own version of Ruby (1.8.7 in `/usr/local/bin/`), I installed `gem` and then all the gems required by Redmine (rails, rake, rubygems-update, etc.). This went a long way in reviving my Redmine app, unfortunately I'm now stuck in "gem hell" as I can't seem to find the right combo of gem versions. Right now (for Redmine 1.1.2) I'm using rails 2.3.11, actionmailer 2.3.11, rake 1.1.2 and rubygems-update 1.5.2. This ought to be a supported combo, but I'm invariably getting the following error: `undefined method 'name' for "actionmailer":String`. Any idea?

Comment: http://www.redmine.org/issues/8325

Comment: Did you do what it said?

Comment: I found part of the culprit: redmine comes with some bits of rails and some gems in the `vendor/` directory; after removing the rails bits and changing `config/environment.rb` to use rails 2.3.12 (I had to update from 2.3.11 to 2.3.12 to fix the actionmailer error) I'm now getting a page of deprecation warnings and the the following error: `Missing these required gems: rubytree >= 0 You're running: ruby 1.8.7.0 at /usr/local/bin/ruby rubygems 1.8.10 at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8, /root/.gem/ruby/1.8 Run 'rake gems:install' to install the missing gems.`

Comment: Yes, I did. Specifically comment #24 describes well the actions I took and matches my current setup: **ruby 1.8.7** (2008-05-31 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux], **gem 1.8.10**, **rubytree 0.8.1**, RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '**2.3.12**' in config/environment.rb, removed `vendor/rails/`. But for some reason rubytree (or maybe another package?) is not found. Current status of the app: http://redmine.appleseedhq.net/. Many thanks for your help quanta!

Comment: No, I mean did you run `sudo rake gems:install`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1583/discussion-between-quanta-and-francois-beaune)